# Velocity reference point when calculating power

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, work, power

[image: Figure]

As shown in the picture, a person (80 kg) is on a platform (20 kg) that's suspended by a rope which is on a pulley. As they pull on the other side of the rope, they reach a constant velocity of 0.4 m/s. **What is the power output of the person?**

I've been confused as to whether I should use the velocity as 0.8 m/s or 0.4 m/s; although the rope is moving at 0.8 m/s through the person's hands, the rope is still only moving at 0.4 m/s from a stationary reference. I'm not sure which one to use when finding power, since 0.8 m/s seems correct, since the person *is* pulling 0.8 meters of rope in one second. However, the rope is only moving 0.4 meters in one second.

Please advise.

Comment: You keep saying “they” yet there is one person. Is there part of this question that you may have left out?

Comment: @Drjh https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they

Comment: As this question will probably be closed for violating the homework policy, I want to leave you a small hint: Suppose someone outside the platform would do the lifting. What would be different? And what would be the same?

Comment: @Bernhard Homework questions are ok if they're primarily conceptual. I suppose this question is borderline, but Jackson isn't asking us to do or check a calculation (which would definitely be off-topic), he just wants some guidance regarding the concepts underlying this exercise.

Answer (score 0):

Power is energy transferred per unit time. $\frac{dE}{dt}$

So that is what you have to do, that is the concept and I think it is enough for you to solve. If you need a deeper explanation you probably violate HW questions policy.

Comment: Thanks. However, since they platform and person are moving at a constant speed, there is no change in kinetic energy, correct? Or do you mean the rate of work done by the person ?

Comment: The Potential energy is still changing though.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about the rope. The key to this exercise is the kinetic energy. In the person's frame, they have zero velocity. To determine the energy, and thence the power, consider the kinetic energy of the person plus the frame relative to the ground.

Answer (score 0):

The mechanical power of a force, $\vec F$, is given by $ P=\vec F \cdot \vec v$ where $\vec v$ is the velocity of the material at the point of application of the force. Just apply this consistently.

In this case the reference frame is implicitly specified as the one in which the platform is going up at 0.4 m/s. In other words, the reference frame is the earth’s frame. In that frame the person’s hand is going down at 0.4 m/s. So the appropriate velocity is $\vec v=-0.4\text{ m/s }\hat i$ where $\hat i $ is the upward-pointing unit vector.

Note that power is frame variant. If you use the reference frame of the platform instead of the earth’s frame then you will get a different power. Energy will be conserved either way, but the power will be different.

Comment: Great, thanks for the clarification. So the force to find power would just be the person's applied force on the rope, not including the tension holding the platform, correct?

Comment: @Jackson each force has its own associated power. I assume from the question that they are only interested in the mechanical power delivered by the person’s hands. But in principle you could calculate the power of any of the forces involved.